# How to stop leksah from replacing chars like the not sign?

Tags: haskell, leksah

I use leksah version 13.3.3.0.
When I have a haskell line like this:

```
let s = "¬" :: String
```

in reality, the source file is not like that.
If I open the source file in emacs, it reads this:

```
let s = "not" :: String
```

How can I stop this behaviour of leksah?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have "ToCandy" option set in your configurations. Menu->Congifuration->ToCandy.